# Symfony 2 +Twig custom form field type - Selected Radio Button

Tags: symfony, twig

I would like auto select value from session on radio button from twig. Unfortunately following code doesn't work for me.

In my twig template

```
{{ form_row(reg_form.sex, {'data' : 2}) }}
```

My form field type (User::SEX_MALE = 1, User::SEX_FEMALE = 2)

```
<?php

namespace FWM\CoreBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

use FWM\CoreBundle\Entity\User;

use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\Options;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

/**
 * A form field for selecting user's sex
 */
class SexType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'choices' => array(
                User::SEX_MALE => 'label.form.male',
                User::SEX_FEMALE => 'label.form.female'
            ),
            'label' => 'label.form.sex',
            'expanded' => true,
        ]);
    }    

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'choice';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'user_sex';
    }
}
```

And my display customization:

```
{% block form_row %}
    {% set error = false %}
    {% if errors %}
        {% set error = true %}
        {% set attr = attr|merge({'class' : attr.class|default('') ~ ' error'}) %}
    {% endif %}
    {{ form_widget(form, {'attr' : attr, 'error': error}) }}
{% endblock form_row %}


{% block choice_widget %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% if expanded %}
        {% set attr = attr|merge({'class' : attr.class|default('') ~ ' radio-row'}) %}

        <div {{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}>

        {{dump(form)}}

        {% for child in form %}

            <span class="unbreakable">{{ form_widget(child) }}&nbsp;{{ form_label(child) }}</span>

        {% endfor %}
        </div>
    {% else %}
...
```

If I add "data => 2" to `setDefaults(...)`, field female becomes selected, but I can't find way to make it work by passing value from twig. Could someone help me please?

Comment: Why would you want to pass things from the template to the object? The template is suppose to be separate from the controller, model, or whatever and i just supposed to create what you have already made.

Comment: By the time the form is available in the `twig` then everything that is or was going to happen to it should have happened. You could set your default in the object class `$this->createFormBuilder(Object, {your options})` and then set it or you could hard code it in your entity.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer, of course when i move logic to controller it works perfect.

Answer (score -3):

@qooplmao wrote in a comment:

> By the time the form is available in the `twig` then everything that is or was going to happen to it should have happened. You could set your default in the object class `$this->createFormBuilder(Object, {your options})` and then set it or you could hard code it in your entity.

Comment: ([Questiona answered in a comment and converted to a community wiki](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments)).